# C# use function in select query to Decrypt table data

Tags: c#, mysql

I try to display the data form `dtls` table to datagridview - Decrypted  - using the function `Decrypt`
The code works fine without the function. Not sure how to implement the function in the select query

```
try
{
    con = new MySqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = constring;
    con.Open();

    MySqlDataAdapter myDA = new MySqlDataAdapter();

    string cmd = "SELECT Decrypt(username) FROM sys.dtls ";

    myDA.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(cmd, con);

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    myDA.Fill(table);
    BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
    bSource.DataSource = table;

    dgvShow.DataSource = bSource;

    {

    }
    con.Close();

    }

catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}

}



public string Decrypt(string cipherText)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
    byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return cipherText;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL doesn't know about your `Decrypt` function. What you have to do is run the query to select the usernames: `SELECT username FROM sys.dtls`, and then iterate over the results and decrypt the username then:

```
myDA.Fill(table);
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    row["username"] = Decrypt(row["username"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thank now no errors but the Datagridview stay empty - any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure. Have you tried debugging it? Put a break-point on the line after the loop finishes to see if the data is there as you expect, and then follow through to see what happens.